# Session management in Facebook applications

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I am new to PHP and am trying to build a facebook application. In the index.php file, I do the following :

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)){ 
       session_start(); 
}
```

the facebook sdk seems to start the session by itself, so my code, doesn't get called at all ! meanwhile, index.php has a form that gets submitted to a new file called processForms.php. In index.php, i set the following:

```
$_SESSION['uid'] = $me['id'];
```

But in processForms.php, accessing $_SESSION gives me the following error:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION
```

Not sure whether I am getting the whole concept of sessions wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an `if` before `session_start`. Just call it straight: `session_start();`. If the session has already been started, it will do no harm.

It seems you get the concept of "starting the session" wrong. Well, not exactly wrong... Look: "session_start()" does **not** "starts the session", in the sense you may be thinking, i.e., you call it **once** and the "session has been 'started'". No. You need to call "session_start" **always**, in the beginning of **every** PHP script which will deal with sessions.

For example, at `login.php`:

```
session_start();
if ($user_and_pass_are_correct)
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
}
```

At `somepage.php`:

```
session_start();
echo 'User name is ' . $_SESSION['username'];
```

You need the "session_start" call there. It does not mean "the beginning of the session". It means "initialize the session stuff, so I can use sessions".

An usual approach is to have a single `session_start` in a "bootstrap" kind of script, and include it in the beginning of all other scripts.

"**bootstrap.php**"

```
<?php
    session_start(); // first line of script
    initialize_other_stuff();
```

"**a_page.php**"

```
<?php
    include('bootstrap.php'); // first line of script
```

"**another_page.php**"

```
<?php
    include('bootstrap.php'); // first line of script, always
```

Comment: If I remove the if, I get the following message on my browser :

Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()

Comment: Alright, you can keep the `if`. I'd change the condition to `if (empty(session_id()))` - see http://br.php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php ("Return Values" section)